# How to render a Table onChange of a select Option IN ReactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a Select Option code like this

```
var SelectOption = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: [],
      empid: null
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    //this.loadOptionfromServer();
    //setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },

  onChange: function(e) {
    var employeeId = e.target.value;
    if (employeeId == 1) {
      this.setState({
        empid: 'xxx'
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({

        empid: employeeId
      })
    }

    this.renderTable();
  },

  renderTable: function() {

    < Tableforbasictask data = {
      data
    }
    />

  },

  render: function() {
    return ( < div >
      < div >
      < h3 > Select Employee to Review < /h3> < SelectOptionList onChange = {
        this.onChange
      }
      data = {
        this.state.data
      }
      /> < /div> {
        this.renderTable()
      } < /div> 
    );

  }
});

var SelectOptionList = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      empid: ''
    };
  },


  render: function() {

    return ( < select id = "select1"
      className = "form-control"
      data - placeholder = "Basic Select2 Box"
      onChange = {
        this.props.onChange
      } > < option value = "1" > Select Employee < /option> < option value = "2" > Some Value < /option><option value="3">Some Value</option > < option value = "4" > Some Value < /option></select >
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( < div className = "row" > < SelectOption / > < /div > , document.getElementById('content'));
```

Then I have a Table COmponent

```
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  taskName: "Pete Hunt",
  standarDescription: "This is one comment",
  emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo",
  empRating: "1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  taskName: "Pete Hunt",
  standarDescription: "This is one comment",
  emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo",
  empRating: "1"
}, {
  id: 3,
  taskName: "Pete Hunt",
  standarDescription: "This is one comment",
  emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo",
  empRating: "1"
}, {
  id: 4,
  taskName: "Pete Hunt",
  standarDescription: "This is one comment",
  emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo",
  empRating: "1"
}, {
  id: 5,
  taskName: "Pete Hunt",
  standarDescription: "This is one comment",
  emplComment: "meaaow I am meeawo",
  empRating: "1"
}];


var Addcontenttotable = React.createClass({
render: function() {
  return ( < tr > < td > {
      this.props.taskName
    } < /td> < td > {
    this.props.standarDescription
  } < /td> < td > {
  this.props.emplComment
} < /td> < td > {
this.props.empRating
} < /td> < /tr > );
}
});

var TableforbasictaskList = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
          return ( < Addcontenttotable taskName = {
              comment.taskName
            }
            standarDescription = {
              comment.standarDescription
            }
            emplComment = {
              comment.emplComment
            }
            empRating = {
              comment.empRating
            }
            key = {
              comment.id
            } >
            < /Addcontenttotable>
          );
        });
        return ( < tbody > {
            commentNodes
          } < /tbody>);
        }
      });

    var Tableforbasictask = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          data: this.props.data
        };
      },
      handleSubmit: function(comment) {
        comment.id = this.state.data.length + 1;
        this.setState({
          data: this.state.data.concat(comment)
        });
      },
      render: function() {
        return ( < div className = "downloadlinks" >
          < table className = "table table-bordered table-striped-col nomargin"
          id = "table-data" >
          < thead >
          < tr align = "center" >
          < td > Task Name < /td> < td > Standard Discription of Task < /td > < td > Employee Comment < /td> < td > Employee rating < /td > < /tr> < /thead >

          < TableforbasictaskList data = {
            this.state.data
          }
          />  < /table >
          < /div>
        );
      }
    });
```

I am tryinig to render the Table only when a An Option from the Select Tag is changed .

But its not happening

here is the [**Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42136/) to the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I did not get the gist of what are you are trying to do, but for sure your function:

```
  renderTable: function() {
     <Tableforbasictask data = {data}/>
  }
```

needs to return the component, so it should be like:

```
  renderTable: function() {
     return <Tableforbasictask data = {data}/>
  }
```

Other thing, in the `onChange` event, you call the `renderTable`, which you don't need to do, the `setState` will automatically call the `render` method of the component that will call the `renderTable`.

Comment: Thank you very much , Actually in my localhost I am taking the value of Option and sending it to the Table Component which calls api to get the details of that ID . Hope I explained my point

Comment: Another issue is when I am selecting the option then next time its not loding the Table component , I have a console.log(this.props.id) on the Table component but inever logs anything

Comment: I just tested your code and the table is rendered every time I changed the selection (I placed a console.log in the render method of the Table)

Comment: yes My bad , But I am having trouble . I explained in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253062/how-to-reload-the-data-of-a-child-when-a-child-component-is-being-rendered-in-re