# How to reload the Data of a child when a child Component is being rendered in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table component which loads the data from an API it looks like this

```
var Tablefortask = React.createClass({

                            getInitialState: function() {
                                      return {data: []};

                              },

                              loadCommentsFromServer: function() {

                                $.ajax({
                                  url: this.props.url+this.props.empId,
                                  dataType: 'json',
                                  cache: false,
                                  success: function(data) {
                                    this.setState({data: data});
                                  }.bind(this),
                                  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                                    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                                  }.bind(this)
                                });

                              },
                                  componentDidMount: function() {

                                    this.loadCommentsFromServer();

                                    //setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
                              },
                              render: function() {
                                return (
                                 <div className="border-basic-task col-md-12">
                                 <div className="col-md-12">
                                 { this.props.empId }
                                  <table className="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped-col " id="table-data">
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr align="center">
                                        <th>Task  Name</th>
                                        <th >Standard Discription of Task</th>
                                        <th>Employee Comment</th>
                                        <th >Employee Rating</th>
                                        <th width="30%">Reviewer Comment</th>
                                        <th >Reviewer Rating</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <TablefortaskList data={this.state.data} />
                                  </table>
                                  </div>
                                  </div>
                                );
                              }
                            });
```

Now this table component is Loaded from a Drop Down which is like this

```
 var SelectOption = React.createClass({

                              getInitialState: function() {
                                      return {  
                                                data: [],
                                                empid:null
                                            };
                              },

                              loadOptionfromServer: function() {

                                $.ajax({
                                  url: this.props.url,
                                  dataType: 'json',
                                  cache: false,
                                  success: function(data) {
                                    this.setState({data: data});
                                    //console.log(data);
                                  }.bind(this),
                                  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                                    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                                  }.bind(this)
                                });

                              },

                              componentDidMount: function() {

                                    this.loadOptionfromServer();
                                    //setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);

                              },

                              onChange: function (e) {

                                  var employeeId = e.target.value;
                                  if(employeeId == 1){
                                        this.setState({
                                          empid:'xxx'
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        this.setState({

                                          empid: employeeId
                                        })
                                    } 


                                },

                              renderTable:function(){

                                    console.log(this.state.empid);
                                    if(this.state.empid){
                                     return (<Tablefortask  url="/appraisal/alltask/" empId= {this.state.empid} pollInterval={70000}  />
                                     );
                                }
                              },

                              render: function() {
                                return (
                                   <div>
                                    <div>
                                      <h3> Select Employee to Review </h3>
                                      <SelectOptionList url={this.props.url} onChange={this.onChange} data={this.state.data} />
                                    </div>
                                         { this.renderTable() }
                                  </div> 
                                );

                              }
                            });
```

Problem is Everytime I change the Select Option I can see the Table component loaded but the AJAX call which is `loadCommentsFromServer` function is not being fired . And It fires only for the First time . 
Any Idea how Can I fix this

I read little bit about `shouldComponentUpdate()` is this what i should be looking for ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever you change the `employeeId` `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` getting called.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {

    if (nextProps.empId !== this.props.empId) {
       this.loadCommentsFromServer(nextProps.empId);
    } 

},

loadCommentsFromServer: function(empId) {

  $.ajax({
     url: this.props.url + empId,
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
     }.bind(this),
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
     }.bind(this)
  });

},
componentDidMount: function() {

    this.loadCommentsFromServer(this.props.empId);

},
```

Add the `componentWillReceiveProps` and pass the `nextProps.empId` with `loadCommentsFromServer`.

Comment: thanks It worked , So Inside `componentWillReceiveProps` the if condition will always be true when ever new props is loaded hence it will load the function . I hope I got it right

Comment: if you are passing multiple props to the child, It might be false also.

Comment: I have another Scenarios where , In the `Tablefortask` component I am defining another `Onchange` function which I am trying to pass to its GrandChildren but I get error as `TypeError: this is undefined`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255421/trying-to-pass-onchange-function-as-props-to-grandchlidren-result-into-typeerror

Answer (score 0):

Each time your Table component is re-render, `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` is called (instead of `componentDidMount` called only once at component first display). Try adding in your component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
},
```

Comment: can you tell what parameter is nextProps ?  , Is  it required to add there ?

Comment: I added this code, But it loads one prop later. Like if I select and ID=1 for the first time its not loading the `loadCommentsFromServer()` function but when I change the select button again it loads the last one